# Load & Plot %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, time

I'm trying to make a simple XY plot using "plot_date" by loading a file with two dates and a value, but haven't yet had success. The idea is to have columns 0 and 1 to represent "time1", and columns 2 and 3 as "time2", and column 4 as "val".

Data input data looks like this:

```
2017-04-08 16:54:37 2017-04-08 16:55:08 1
2017-04-08 16:58:28 2017-04-08 16:58:33 1
2017-04-08 17:02:18 2017-04-08 17:02:24 1
```

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.cm
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter
import datetime as dt

time1,time2,val = np.loadtxt(inputfile, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True, converters = {0,1: strpdate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})
```

Here I get an error:

```
>>> time1,time2,val = np.loadtxt(inputfile, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True, converters = {0,1: strpdate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})
File "<stdin>", line 1
time1,time2,val = np.loadtxt(inputfile, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True, converters = {0,1: strpdate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong? Suggestions on how to correct it?

Among other things, I'm hoping to subtract time2 from time1 and get the difference in seconds. Is this possible?

Finally, I'd like to plot the variables, something along the lines of:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(time1, val, 'b-', color='b')
ax.plot_date(time2, val, 'b-', color='g')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert every column separately and then combine it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.cm
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter
import datetime as dt

time1,date1,time2,date2,val = np.loadtxt(inputfile, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4),  unpack=True,
 converters = {0: strpdate2num("%Y-%m-%d"), 1: strpdate2num("%H:%M:%S"),
 2: strpdate2num("%Y-%m-%d"), 3: strpdate2num("%H:%M:%S")})

time1 += date1
time2 += date2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(time1, val, 'b-', color='b')
ax.plot_date(time2, val, 'b-', color='g')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: ok cool! One last question: if I do time_diff = time2 - time1, how can I print time_diff and show its contents as seconds?

Comment: Matplotlib stores dates in days => `dt = t1-t2; seconds = dt * 24 * 60 *60`. 24*60*60 = seconds in a day.